# Connect to Azure SQL Server in PCF using Connection Strings

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, azure, cloud-foundry

I have created a .NET Core application with SQL Server EF. I need to host my application in PCF. Is it possible to connect to my Cloud SQL Server through the Connection String in PCF?

Thanks,
Siva

Answer (score 0):

Sure You can connect your applications on PCF to SQLServer running, provided they are on same network. You can directly create the CUPS service on your space in PCF and read the configuration from your application through VCAP_SERVICES variable and use inside the application.

Standard way of doing this is to expose you SQL server as service in your cloud foundry instance, create a service inside your space and then bind your application to that service.

```
https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/user-provided.html
```

Comment: Yeah I'm looking for another approach of directly connecting via "Connection Strings" instead of Cups.

Comment: You can do that provided that PCF and SQLServer are on same network.

Comment: Understood. If in the case, My Cloud Foundry is hosted in AWS and SQL Server is in Azure, can I connect it?

Comment: Yeah you can do it. You need to have a security group and open outbound port in your AWS. This allows AWS firewall to allow apps connect to different network. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html    Likewise you need to open SQLServer port in Azure as well. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sqlclassic/virtual-machines-windows-classic-sql-connect#connect-to-sql-server-over-the-internet            After doing this then u can connect. This may not be a performant, since there are always network latencies involved.

Comment: I'm using Azure SQL Server service. I'm not using SQL Server VM. I added my client IP in the Firewall settings of Azure SQL Server.